# generate a jlist on a "submit" button click

Tags: java

I am developing a java desktop application using netbeans. I have a panel to which I want to add a jlist whose items and values have to be added dynamically. Also, I want this Jlist to be created after hitting a "submit" button on the page. How do I achieve this ? I tried adding an action to the button and writing the code there. But, it is not generating any list.

Any help in this regard would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please, paste the code you have written. Otherwise we won't be able to see what's going on.

Comment: @Cristian: @Action
    public void getmethodsinlist() {
String[] items = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
JList list1 = new JList(items);
mainPanel.add(list1);

Comment: The action is associated with the button click. Also I am writing this in DesktopapplicationView.java

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you add components to a visible GUI the basic code is:

```
JList list = new JList(...);
panel.add( list );
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

If your GUI was designed using the IDE then it probably uses GroupLayout, in which case the code is far more complex because you need to specify the GroupLayout constraints when you add the component. In this case my advice is to dump the GUI designer and do the GUI layout yourself by using the appropriate combination of layout managers.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the GUI was designedd using Netbeans IDE and it does not allow me to modify the code.

Comment: Also, what exactly I need to achieve is explained below: I need to populate a list whose items are the names of methods of a java class. So I need to execute a method which gets the names of methods of class using java reflection. All this has to be done before the frame loads.                                                           Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: At design time you create your JList and add it to a JScrollPane and add the scroll panel to the GUI. The you create a DefaultListModel and at data to the model. Then you can use list.setModel(...) to update the JList.